# fgetcsv line endings

Tags: php, fgetcsv

Hi I have a fgetcsv function that reads a CSV file and exports the data into a list. This works, and I have used this function numerous times elsewhere with no problems.

The relevant bits of the code are:

```
ini_set("auto_detect_line_endings", true);

$file = fopen($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'],"r");


while (($data = fgetcsv($file, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE)
   {
   $body_data['user_list'][] = $data;
   }

fclose($file);
```

The problem is that the read CSV stops at any spaces (white space) between words in columned data.

I thought that `auto_detect_line_endings` would solve this, could it be that this is causing the problem?

Comment: How can you tell that it stops at any white space? You code seems fine, though I always use `fgetcsv($file)`, omitting max-length and delimiter.

Comment: for example if one column of the csv file contains "The Data", the uploaded list will simply display "The" for that column. it seems it is seeing the space as newline? I agree though, I dont think the maxlength and delimiter specified would make this error.

Comment: What if you have a row like `col1,col2,"The Data",col4`? Does it got read as `col1,col2,The,col4` or `col1,col2,The`?

Comment: nope it carries on witht the rest of the read fine. so like `col1,col2,The,col4`

Comment: So it's not "stop" or "treat space as newline". How did you check to find out that things after spaces are truncated? Did you do things like `print_r($body_data['user_list'])`?

Comment: I only know as the data is populating a list that is in use elsewhere in the system. The data in the list is truncated.

Comment: This behavior is very unexpected. I would suggest you to do some debugging to get more information, like `print_r($data)` in `while`, `print_r($body_data['user_list'])` after `while`, and also debug the part where the data is populated.

Answer (score 1):

Change your while loop with this

```
while (!feof($file) ) {
        $body_data['user_list'][] = fgetcsv($file, 1024);
    }
```